# Link to the end of a section

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Test~A}
\label{section:test-a-start}
\lipsum

\subsection{Test~A2}
\lipsum\\[\baselineskip]
\label{section:test-a-end}

\section{Test~B}
\label{section:test-b}
The former section ranges from page~\pageref{section:test-a-start} to \pageref{section:test-a-end}.

\end{document}
```

It seems to me that `\pageref{section:test-a-end}` gives the page number at the very end of the first section which is what I want.

However, when using [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), `\pageref{section:test-a-end}` links to the beginning of the last subsection. Can I somehow link to the end of the subsection (and thereby the end of the section) rather than to the beginning of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a `\phantomsection` to mark a different location to what was set with the previous `\refstepcounter`:

```
\phantomsection\label{section:test-a-end}
```